# Laravel 5 - Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My problem is, when i try to call a class from my controller, `Laravel` returns that did not found the class

**In my controller:**

```
$get_connections = Mail_server_connection::get_connection();
print_r($get_connections);
```

**Error:**

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)    
Class 'App\models\Mail_server_connection' not found
```

It is the first time that i occur this error, i want also to notice that i have modified the `auth.php` and the `User.php` model in order to change `Laravel's` default `User.php` to a custom one with a custom table in `MySql`

Any suggestion will be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change my model's class name from `Mail_server_connection`
to `MailServerConnection` and everything worked just fine. Looks like the underscores were not valid for `Laravel`.

So my new question is Why?!

Comment: Did you import the class through the `use` keyword at the top of the page?

Comment: @JoelHinz No but why? I thought laravel takes responsibility for that..!

Comment: @Makis Laravel 5 needs you to include every class using `use` function. I don't know why they did that

Comment: Strange!! Thanks you all by the way

Comment: It's not a requirement of Laravel. In general you need to import classes using "use" statement if you want to use class names without specifying fully qualified class path so that autoloader knows which class to load, as there might be multiple classes with the same name withing single project

Comment: What's the files name?

Comment: Nice Answer @jedrzej.kurylo. I understand the reason why now.

Comment: @michael The file's name is the same as the class name.

Comment: Exactly same spelled? With underscores?

Comment: Yes, no i converted it in camelcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to autoloading standards your file name has to be the same as the file name is, so having a file called

```
fooBar.php
```

holding a class called

```
 foo_bar
```

will not work. That's not laravel, this is php.

Then, having a file within the namespace

```
App\Http\Controllers
```

will require you to provide either the full namespace name with a leading \, for example

```
$foo = new \App\FooBar
```

every time you use it and the class used isn't in the exactly same namespace, or you can `use` it at the top of your file like

```
use App\FooBar;
```

once and then reuse the class directly within your file. Please note that there's no leading \ needed in this case.

Sidenote

If you have multiple classes with the same name in different namespaces, you can define an alias in the `use` statement:

```
use App\FooBar as Baz;
```

will make the class available as `Baz`.

Comment: Great answer Michael, Finally i understood!

Answer (score -1):

Here you need to update your composer and npm- run this command ()

Comment: With all due respect, NPM is Nodejs related 

Comment: It's always a good idea to understand the problem the OP is asking and present your possible solution in a way that makes it easy to understand the "why".
Your current answer does not exactly help the OP; kudos for attempting to answer, keep it up.